# Django - System architecture for reusing user registration form on multiple pages

Tags: html, django, forms, architecture

I was figuring how to reuse the same registration form and view on multiple templates and pages, and in different formats. E.g. on the page, in a modal etc. I am however some trouble in figuring out the best practice for solving this problem. One thing I am actively trying to avoid is repeating myself, but I can't seem to find a solution that is satisfying enough.

At the moment I have one central view that handles user registrations that looks like this. At the moment it can only handle to output one form on the signup_form template, but I want to extend that to the index page and be able to be outputted in a modal as well.

## Views.py

```
def signup(request):
    template_name = 'core/authentication/signup_form.html'
    custom_error_list = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Check for duplciate email
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists():
                custom_error_list.append("A user with that email already exists")

            else:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                subject = 'Activate your StockPy Account'
                sender = '' #Insert sender address here
                message = render_to_string('core/authentication/account_activation_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)
                })
                user.email_user(subject, message)
                return redirect('authentication:account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'custom_error_list': custom_error_list})

#Activate the user as he/she clicks the email verification link which lead to tihs view
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        #Using a [:1] is ad-hoc solution to get rid of the starting 'b' symbol
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64[1:]))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(template_name)
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/authentication/account_activation_invalid.html')
```

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email','password']

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email...', 'class' : 'form-control', 'pattern' : '[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Username...',
        })
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Password...',
            'type': 'password',
        })
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Password again...',
            'type': 'password',
        })
```

My signup form currently looks like this.

## signup_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<!-- End Navbar -->
{% block page-header %}
<div class="section section-signup" style="background-image: url({% static 'core/assets/img/bg8.jpg' %}); background-size: cover; background-position: top center; min-height: 700px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card card-signup" data-background-color="orange">
                <form class="form" method="POST" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="header text-center">
                        <h4 class="title title-up">Sign Up</h4>
                        <div class="social-line">
                            <a href="#twitter" class="btn btn-neutral btn-twitter btn-icon btn btn-round">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#facebook" class="btn btn-neutral btn-facebook btn-icon btn-lg btn-round">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#google" class="btn btn-neutral btn-google btn-icon btn-round">
                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <!-- Output error messages -->
                        {% for field in form %}
                            <div style="color:red; list-decorations:none;" class="text-center">
                                {{ field.errors.as_text }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for error in custom_error_list %}
                            <div style="color:red;" class="text-center">
                                * {{ error }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                        <!-- Output all fields -->
                        {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="input-group form-group-no-border">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="now-ui-icons
                                    {% if field.name == 'email' %} ui-1_email-85{% endif %}
                                    {% if field.name == 'username' %} users_circle-08{% endif %}
                                    {% if field.name == 'password1' %} ui-1_lock-circle-open{% endif %}
                                    {% if field.name == 'password2' %} ui-1_lock-circle-open{% endif %}
                                "></i>
                            </span>
                            {{ field }}

                            <!-- Give input box red border if data is not valid -->
                            {% if field.errors %}
                                <script>
                                    var element = document.getElementById("{{ field.id_for_label }}");
                                    element.classList.add("form-control-danger");
                                </script>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                        <div class="text-center">
                            Already registered? <a href="#" style="color:blue;">Log in here</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- If you want to add a checkbox to this form, uncomment this code -->
                        <!-- <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="checkboxSignup" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkboxSignup">
                                Unchecked
                                </label>
                            </div> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round btn-lg">Get Started</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock page-header %}
```

And a small example snippet of my index.html of how I want to implement it ish.

## index.html

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="section section-about-us">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have really tried to find a smooth way of doing this, but without result unfortunately.

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. There is no error. It is a question about what is the best practice. I can't find any solution without repeating already existing code, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you already know how to implement the same form in multiple templates, but you've having trouble avoiding repetition in your code. To that end, here are some suggestions for reducing the amount of repetition you'll encounter when duplicating this form across multiple pages:

- **Validate data within your form rather than your view.** Currently, you are checking for duplicate e-mail addresses within views.py. If you duplicated your form, you'd have to re-write that code all over again. Instead, why not move it into forms.py in a custom cleaning method (see [Django docs on custom form cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)).
- **Write functions for actions that will be repeated**. For example, currently, you are sending an activation e-mail to your user within views.py. It makes more sense to write a function within your user/models.py called something like `send_activation_email().` Whenever you want to send an activation e-mail to a user, you can then call `user.send_activation_email()` rather than duplicating your entire block of activation e-mail code (see [Django docs on model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods)).
- **Use inclusion tags to avoid repetition in your templates.** If there's a block of code that you find yourself repeating in your templates, you can use Django's inclusion tags to include a snippet of HTML across multiple templates. This allows you to serve the same form in multiple locations without re-writing your code. If you want to style your form differently across multiple pages, you could wrap it in DIVs with different IDs and use CSS to style the form differently depending on which DIV it's wrapped in. (see [Django docs on inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags))

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a question though. My User model is Django's default model. How do I exactly modify its Model Methods in a correct way?

Comment: This article is a great place to start: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html. For what it's worth, I always create a custom user model at the beginning of every Django project precisely so that I can modify in the future as needed.